# Mapping subdomain to point to sudirectory site in WordPress Multisite Network

Tags: multisite, nginx

I installed WordPress multisite (the sites runs in the root folder) and have created a site as a subdirectory. The web server used is Nginx.

I now want to map the main domain example.com to the parent site, and subdomain.example.com to the child site, which is installed in a subdirectory.

I tried using WordPress MU domain mapping, but I am not sure if it works for me. I am unable to test using my computer's hosts file.

The question is: Is it possible to get domain.example.com to point to mysite.com/subdirectory in a multisite network?

UPDATE: When I try to use WordPress MU domain mapping, and add an entry for the child site under Tools > Domain Mapping, I get a message 'New domain added'. But the new entry is not listed anywhere. What could be happening?

[image]

Comment: the answer is yes, assuming it is the same domain and not different ones.

Comment: Yes, the domain is the same. example.com and subdomain.example.com is what I need for my Multisite subdir install. Will it be complex to do it? Will I need any database changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was!

Whenever I went to Settings > Domain Mapping under the Network Admin panel, I always got a message: "Domain mapping database table created."

In fact, that database table was never created. The database user never had CREATE privileges.

Once I granted CREATE to the user, I was able to get subdomain.example.com to point to example.com/subdirectory.